# What to watch out for when converting a std::string to a char* for C function?

Tags: c++, c, string, char, c++-faq

I have read many posts asking the question on how to convert a C++ `std::string` or `const std::string&` to a `char*` to pass it to a C function and it seems there is quite a few caveat's in regards to doing this.  One has to beware about the string being contiguous and a lot of other things.  The point is that I've never really understood all the points one needs to be aware of and **why**?

I wondered if someone could sum up the caveats and downfalls about doing a conversion from a `std::string` to a `char*` that is needed to pass to a C function?

This when the `std::string` is a `const` reference and when it's just a non-const reference, and when the C function will alter the `char*` and when it will not alter it.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://programmedlessons.org/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-20/ass20_2.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string

Comment: That's actually a very good question and it has caused pretty good answers. Should we make this an [FAQ entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq)?

Comment: @sbi: I think that's probably a good idea, it's not an uncommon thing to come across and I'm sure I'm not the first and last that will wonder or be confused about this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, whether const reference or value doesn't change anything.

You then have to consider what the function is expecting.  There
are different things which a function can do with a `char*` or
a `char const*`---the original versions of `memcpy`, for
example, used these types, and it's possible that there is still
such code around.  It is, hopefully, rare, and in the following,
I will assume that the `char*` in the C function refer to `'\0'`
terminated strings.

If the C function takes a `char const*`, you can pass it the
results of `std::string::c_str()`; if it takes a `char*`, it
depends.  If it takes a `char*` simply because it dates from the
pre-`const` days of C, and in fact, it modifies nothing,
`std::string::c_str()` followed by a `const_cast` is
appropriate.  If the C function is using the `char*` as an out
parameter, however, things become more difficult.  I personally
prefer declaring a `char[]` buffer, passing this, and then
converting the results to `std::string`, but all known
implementations of `std::string` use a contiguous buffer, and
the next version of the standard will require it, so correctly
dimensioning the `std::string` first (using
`std::string::resize()`, then passing `&s[0]`, and afterwards
redimensionning the string to the resulting length (determined
using `strlen(s.c_str())`, if necessary) can also be used.

Finally (but this is also an issue for C programs using
`char[]`), you have to consider any lifetime issues.  Most
functions taking `char*` or `char const*` simply use the
pointer, and forget it, but if the function saves the pointer
somewhere, for later use, the string object must live at least
as long, and its size should not be modified during that period.
(Again, in such cases, I prefer using a `char[]`.)

Comment: +1 Thank you! For the case of a C function taking a char* and modifying it, I have used the `&s[0]` "hack" in the past, but I never did the final resize afterward. I recently ran into a strange problem with ostringstream trying to use the resulting (unresized) `s` string, and it silently disabled the stringstream. Using a regular char[] for C functions is now my preferred method as well, it's simpler and safer.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, there are three points that are important:

- According to the still current standard, `std::string` isn’t actually guaranteed to use contiguous storage (as far as I know this is due to change). But in fact, all current implementations probably use contiguous storage anyway. For that reason, `c_str()` (and `data()`) may actually create a *copy* of the string internally …
- The pointer returned by `c_str()` (and `data()`) is valid only as long as no non-const methods on the original string are invoked. This makes its use unsuitable when the C function hangs on to the pointer (as opposed to only using it during the duration of the actual function call).
- If there is *any* chance at all that the string is going to be modified, casting away constness from the `c_str()` is not a good idea. You **must** create a buffer with a copy of the string, and pass that into the C function. If you create a buffer, remember to add a null termination.

Comment: `c_str()` must be constant time, so cannot make a copy. But it is allowed to keep a separate copy all the time, so your second point still holds.

Comment: @Sjoerd I’m not sure; can you point me to the paragraph where it says this in the standard? §21.3.6 doesn’t have any complexity constraints for the functions.

Comment: @Sjoerd: I have just rechecked the standard, and I cannot find a runtime requirement on `.c_str()`, can you provide a reference as to where in the standard is `.c_str()` required to be a constant time operation?

Comment: This misses the IMO very important aspect of lifetime of what `.c_str()` returns.

Answer (score 4):

[I would add a comment, but I don't have enough rep for that, so sorry for adding (yet) another answer.]

While it is true that the **current** standard does not guarantee the internal buffer of std::string to be contiguous, it appears that practically all implementations use contiguous buffers. Furthermore, the new C++0x standard (which is about to be approved by ISO) requires contiguous internal buffers in std::string, and even the current C++03 standard requires returning a contiguous buffer when you call data() or &str[0] (though it won't be necessarily null-terminated). See [here](http://herbsutter.com/2008/04/07/cringe-not-vectors-are-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous/#comment-483) for more details.

That still doesn't make it safe to write to the string though, since the standard doesn't force implementations to *actually return their internal buffer* when you call data(), c_str() or operator, and neither are they prevented from using optimizations like copy-on-write, which may complicate things further (it appears that the new C++0x will ban ban copy-on-write though). That being said, if you don't care about maximum portability, you can check your target implementation and see what it actually does inside. AFAIK, Visual C++ 2008/2010 always returns the real internal buffer pointer, and doesn't do copy-on-write (it does have the Small String Optimization, but that's probably not a concern).

Comment: Can you point out why `&str[0]` should refer to the begin of a contiguous buffer?

Comment: I actually learned that first from Herb Sutter:
http://herbsutter.com/2008/04/07/cringe-not-vectors-are-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous/#comment-483

But reading the standard, my understanding is that str[pos] is (and must be) equivalent to data()[pos], and there fore &str[0] is equivalent to &data()[0] which is, in turn, equivalent to data(). And data() itself (as well as c_str()) is required to point to a contiguous buffer.

Comment: That's weird - `data()` returns a `const char*`, but `operator[]` returns a non-const `char&`.

Comment: @MSalters
This is what the C++03 standard has to say:

"`const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;`
`reference operator[](size_type pos);`
1 Returns: If pos < size(), returns data()[pos].
Otherwise, if pos == size(), the const version returns charT(). Otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

----- I guess that it doesn't take const-correctness into account for the non-const version.

Comment: Ah, right - the non-contiguous doubts were with the iterator interface, not the index interface [LWG 530](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#530)

Comment: Update: The VC++ implementation of operator[](pos) basically just returns internal_buffer[pos].

Answer (score 2):

When the C function does **not** alter the string behind the `char*`, you can use `std::string::c_str()` for both const and non-const `std::string` instances.  Ideally it would be a `const char*`,  but if it's not (because of a legacy API) you may legally use a `const_cast`.
But you may only use the pointer from `c_str()` as long as you're not modifying the string!

When the C function does alter the string behind the `char*`, your only safe and portable way to use the `std::string` is to copy it to a temporary buffer yourself (for example from `c_str()`)! Make sure you free the temporary memory afterwards -- or use `std::vector`, which is guaranteed to have continuous memory.

Answer (score 1):

1. std:string can store zero bytes. This means that when passed to C function it can be truncated prematurely, as C functions will stop on first zero byte. This can have security implications, if you try to use C function for example to filter out or escape unwanted characters.
2. A result of std::string::c_str() will sometimes be invalidated by operations changing a string (non-const member functions). It will cause very hard to diagnose bugs ("Heisenbugs") if you try to use this pointer after you first use c_str() and then modify a string.
3. Do not use `const_cast`, ever. `goto` is less troublesome.

Comment: @Tony Tometzky wanted to emphasise that even `goto` is more innocuous than using a `const_cast`. I don’t agree though. `const_cast` has its place. I’ve yet to find a valid use of `goto` (and I *have* read the Knuth paper).