# Which is the best way to read binary file content to std::string?

Tags: c++, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use istream with strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510923/how-to-use-istream-with-strings)

```
std::ifstream ifile(absolute_file_path.c_str(),std::ios::binary | std::ios::in | std::ios::ate);
if (ifile.is_open()==false) 
{
    throw std::runtime_error("Unable open the file.");
}
std::stirng file_content;
//here I need good way to read full file to file_content
//note: the file is binary
ifile.close();
```

This are ways I know:

1.Maybe not safe

```
file_content.resize(ifile.tellg());
ifile.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);
if(!ifile.read(const_cast<char *>(file_content.data()), file_content.size()));
{
    throw std::runtime_errro("failed to read file:");
}
ifile.close();
```

2.Slow

```
file_content.reserve(ifile.tellg());
ifile.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);
while(ifile)
{
    file_content += (char)(ifile.get());
}
```

Comment: You may find this answer to another question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632572/what-to-watch-out-for-when-converting-a-stdstring-to-a-char-for-c-function/5632723#5632723

Comment: a string is not designed to hold binary data, you should use something like a vector<char>

Comment: I'd say the first is much better than the second

Comment: @CharlesB then why it has member function data()?

Comment: @Mihran it doesn't mean that it can be used to hold binary data. Also as you pointed it, it unsafe to use it for write access, see [cplusplus ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/).

Comment: You should better use `while (ifile)` instead of `while (!ifile.eof())` (this could turn into a endless loop).

Comment: @CharlesB: Strings can hold binary data just fine. cplusplus.com is a poor reference. Nobody is suggesting writing through a `const char*`.

Comment: see this question for the right way to read a binary file: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4761529/11343

Comment: Or, better yet, activate an exception on fail.

Comment: @Mihran: [Looping with `!stream.eof()` is wrong.](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.5)

Comment: @Tomalak I'm not saying you can't use strings to hold binary, just that it's not made for it. And yes, Mihran is using const_casted data() to write content, which is far from being elegant, although it works

Comment: 2 more links on the subject: [C++ STL's String eqivalent for Binary Data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/837521/11343) and [“Proper” way to store binary data with C++/STL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/441203/11343)

Comment: @CharlesB: I would also pick `vector<char>`, personally. But you did say "a string is not designed to hold binary data", which is misleading because there is no reason that it cannot.

Answer (score 4):

If the file is binary, it might contain `'\0'` which is a weird character to be contained in an `std::string`. Although I think you could do that, you will be asking for problems because some operations on a `std::string` take a `const char*` which is null-terminated. Instead, go with `std::vector<char>`, a much safer way.

If you go with strings anyway, just do a loop calling `std::string::append(size_t, char)`.

```
while(!ifile.eof()) {
   contents.append(1, ifile.get());
}
```

EDIT: I think you can also do something in the lines of:

```
std::string contents(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifile), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Comment: Start with simple solution, optimize later if you have real life data showing it is slow. Premature optimization is the root of all evil -- DonaldKnuth

Comment: Which `std::string` operations take `const char*`? Some overloads allow _input_ from a `char` array, but _`std::string` is NULL-safe`_

Comment: The constructor `std::string(const char* s)`, the `operator+=(const char* s)` etc all take a `const char*` as parameter, this means that if the argument has a NULL then it will be interpreted as end of string slicing part of what you actually wanted.

Comment: Sure, but they are only provided for convenience, and `std::string` overloads exist (and are preferred) for the same inputs. There's nothing inherent in an `std::string` that's NULL-terminated. The analogy here is that you _still have to use, say, `strlen`_ if you copied a C-string into a `std::vector<char>`. Also note that you can provide an explicit size to the first of those functions.

Answer (score -1):

You should be clear with binary file and string. Do you mean to read the content of that file, or you want to read binary representation of the file to string? Normally an `unsigned char[]` buffer is used to store content of binary files. And `string` is used to store content of a text file.

Comment: why not? it's unsigned char, and in Windows it's BYTE. Please focus on the idea, not this kind of detail!

Comment: OK, I should be more careful next time :-)

Comment: Noooooo do not recommend raw arrays. There is absolutely no reason for that.

Comment: Why not? It depends on your purpose. Usually we read binary file to care about every single byte (or so) to process data. So using raw arrays may help process data easier and faster. If you know in advance the filesize is no way larger than a number of bytes, simply use a fixed array, or if not, use dynamic array instead (there are many ways to do this, I would not say in detail if needless)

Comment: Is a raw `char[]` or a dynamically allocated array (`char*`) significantly faster (if at all faster) than a `vector<char>`? Because a `vector<char>` has obvious advantages, the most important being the facts that it doesn't forget its own size, and that it doesn't require manual memory management.

Comment: Ok I agree. char[] only faster in a very tiny amount of time. Thank you.

Comment: @Martinho: `char*` is not a dynamically allocated array (though it may point to one). And, no, [arrays do not have to be faster than vectors](http://www.xs4all.nl/~weegen/eelis/vector-speed.cpp).